# Which one is better performance to use for .click in the below list

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Please vote for me which one in the below list is better?

I have HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <button class="btn">Click Here 1</button>
    <button class="btn">Click Here 2</button>
    <button class="btn">Click Here 3</button>
    <button class="btn">Click Here 4</button>
    <button class="btn">Click Here 5</button>
    <button class="btn">Click Here 6</button>
    <!-- A lot of buttons -->
    <button class="btn">Click Here n - 2</button>
    <button class="btn">Click Here n - 1</button>
    <button class="btn">Click Here n</button> 
</div>
```

And Javascript with jQuery is:

#### Case 1.1:

```
$(".btn").click(function(e){
    //@todo something here
});
```

#### Case 1.2:

```
var doSomething = function(e)
{
    //@todo something here
}
$(".btn").click(doSomething);
```

#### Case 2:

```
$("#container").click(function(e){
    if( $(e.target).is(".btn") )
    {
        //@todo something here
    }
});
```

I am confused a litle bit what are different between them?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: You are correct me :), I mean how a bout performance, such as: memory?

Comment: Case 2 will automatically catch elements added to the document _after_ the event handler is setup, which in most cases is a good thing. If for some reason you want to set a handler only for events that match the selector _right now_ even if they cease to match that selector in future, or you don't want to match elements added in future, then you'd have to use Case 1.1 or 1.2. Note also that Case 2 can be done more easily using [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or (for version 1.7+) [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the new jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", doSomething);
```

so that

- dynamically added content will be covered
- jQuery won't have to waste time searching out, and wrapping all affected buttons with the handler; all clicks will propogate up to the context, and jQuery will apply them if they match the selector—`.btn` in this case

If you know that all your buttons will be in #container, then you would use *that* as the context, instead of document.

```
$("#container").on("click", ".btn", doSomething);
```

Comment: This uses much less memory than `$(".btn").click` since `on` won't search the whole dom looking for .btn matches, and wrapping the click handler on each.  That's why the docs recommend this method for all event handling needs

Answer (score 2):

Case 1.1 and 1.2 are essentially the same.  The only thing you gain from 1.2 is that you can call the function independently.  If this is a need, then 1.2 should be used, if not, either is fine.

Case 2 is actually not functionally equivalent to the others.  This is essentially equivalent to `live`.  Using `click` will only attach to matching elements at the time `click` is called.  Case 2 (and `live`) will match the selector at the time the event happens.  If any `.btn` elements have been added after this code is called.  Case 2 will let you click on them as well.

EDIT: Note that in 1.7 `live` is replaced by `on` with certain parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 would be the best if you plan to use `doSomething` somewhere else as well. If not, both 1 and 2 are equally good. Of course, only talking style-wise... functionality is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1.1 is a common anonymous function for your event handler and is the most often used case.

Case 1.2 you would use if you also want to call the function directly, not only as an event handler, so you need some way to refer to it.

Case 2 is useful if you have a very large number of things, because it creates only one event handler instead of many.  This case will also catch new items of class `btn` that are dynamically added to `#container`

Comment: What would be the problem with many event handlers? They'd point all to the same function. Or is it a jQuery design problem?

Comment: I have the same question as Bergi?

Comment: @Bergi - it's not a jQuery design problem (you can achieve the same effects in "plain" JavaScript, with the same issues). But you asked about memory: many handlers pointed at the same function is still many handlers. I don't think it's that big a problem given that most "normal" web pages will not have hundreds or thousands of elements all needing an event handler.

Comment: Thanks for that response nnnnnn, I've also read somewhere else here on SO that having many handlers can degrade performance, but I don't know the truth of that statement. I never had a case where I had to be concerned about it, but I'd keep that in mind in a case like this. That, @Bergi and vietean, is why I mentioned it.